Using Serilog Expressions Rest( ) function to show only the remaining non-referenced properties
I am trying to "lift" some properties into the top-level of the output, and I'm using Serilog Expressions, so I want the rest of the non-referenced properties to be output under properties but without repeating the already-referenced ones.
Log Config and Logging Example
var template = 
    "{ { timestamp: @t, level: @l, message: @m, message_template: @mt, " +
    "my_prop_1: @p['MyProp1'], " +
    "other_properties: rest(false) " +
    "} }" + Environment.NewLine;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(new ExpressionTemplate(template), "C:\\Logs\\Log.log")
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();

using(LogContext.PushProperty("MyProp1", "Test ABC"))
{
    Log.Information("Hello {@User}", new { Id = 1234, Name = "John Smith" });
}

Output
{
    "timestamp": "...",
    "level": "Information",
    "message": "Hello {\"Id\":1234,\"Name\":\"John Smith\"}",
    "message_template": "Hello {@User}",
    "my_prop_1": "Test ABC",
    "other_properties": {
        "User": {
            "Id": 1234,
            "Name": "John Smith"
        },
        "MyProp1": "Test ABC"
    }
}

The property MyProp1 is showing up in the output twice. Am I misunderstanding the way the Rest() function works and its intended purpose?
Is there another way to show specific LogContext properties and have the rest show up dynamically?
Side Note: What I'm Really After
This is all because I want to have the log JSON output use snake_case for property names, instead of default PascalCase. Using Serilog Expressions lets me individually rename properties using approach like template: @t but if there are other ways to achieve snake case (via Serilog Expressions or otherwise), I'd love to know them.
